# Manipulate (root) Files from (subdomain)

Tags: php

Domain: domain.com
Subdomain: sub.domain.com

My HTML page on *(subdomain)* needs to show image from *(root)* folder "../../../httpdocs/images/".

User can change that image, so he chose new image and submits the form to the PHP script on *(subdomain)*.

PHP script on *(subdomain)* check's the posted image and resizes it and if all ok...

```
if (imagegif($thenewimage,"../../../httpdocs/images/test.gif",100))
{
   header("location: index.php?success=true");
}
```

then it need's to save it to *(root)* domain.

how to acomplish that? :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `copy` you can copy a file.

http://www.php.net/copy

Comment: copy(from_subdomain,to_root);

yes ok but how?